# insert data into one table from another table on specific condition

Tags: mysql

I have "table1" in which master data store like -

```
id  name    create_date validity    expire_date
    1   A       2015-08-01  3           2015-11-01
    2   B       2015-09-01  12          2016-08-01
    3   C       2015-09-15  1           2015-10-15
```

But now want to insert data in "table2" for expire_date according to validity period like without changing in front end. using trigger or procedure want to achieve this task.

```
   id    parent_id   expire_date   
    1     1           2015-09-01
    2     1           2015-10-01
    3     1           2015-11-01
```

How can I achieve this using procedure or trigger.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: What did you try so far, what is the problem with your best solution? SO is not a code generator service, please show some effort. Also please read the [ask] article in [help].

Comment: Thanks Pred. Query solved by using trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be specific because your question is not specific.

In general, here's the procedure to follow to design a query to insert stuff from one table into another.

**First**, write a `SELECT` query yielding a resultset containing the rows and columns you want inserted into your table.  Use a list of columns to get the right columns, and appropriate `WHERE` clauses to get the right rows. Eyeball that query and that resultset to make sure it contains the correct information.

**Second**, prepend that debugged `SELECT` query with

```
INSERT INTO target_tablename (col, col, col)
```

Test this to make sure the correct rows are being inserted into your target table.

**Third**, create yourself an `EVENT` in your MySQL server to run the query you have just written. The event will, at the appropriate times of day, run your query.

If you take these steps out of order, you'll probably be very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve the task using Store Procedure -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addexpire`(IN uname varchar(50), IN cdate date, IN vm int)
BEGIN
    insert into table1 (name,create_date,validity) values (uname,cdate,vm);
    BEGIN
    declare uparent_id INT;
    declare v_val int default 0;
    SET uparent_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    while v_val < vm do
        BEGIN
            declare expire_date date;   
            SET expire_date =  DATE_ADD(cdate,INTERVAL v_val+1 MONTH);
            insert into table2 (parent_id,expire_date) values (uparent_id,expire_date);
            set v_val=v_val+1;
        END;
    end while;
  END;
END
```